# net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection is closed

Tags: hibernate, tomcat6, quartz-scheduler, postgresql-9.2

I am facing this problem on one of my production environments. It happens quite often but not always at the same segments of the application, it's pretty random.

The application deployed on this environment is very similar to others deployed on different machines, wich used the same technologies and close settings, but the error only occurs on this one so it's being difficult trying to find out the problem.

I must say these errors have started to appear recently, since several update changes:

Application migrated from Windows to Linux

PostgresSQL 8.2 to 9.2

Tomcat 5 to Tomcat 6

All these changes also have been done on the rest of the deployed applications which have not experienced any problem at all.

The technologies used by the applications are:

Hibernate 2.1.6

PostgreSQL 9.2

Tomcat 6.0.35

The configuration in the context.xml is:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/psa" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/psa?compatible=7.4"
        username="xxx" password="xxx" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="10000" factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
        defaultAutoCommit="false" removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true" validationQuery="select 1"
        testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="true" testWhileIdle="true"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000"/>
```

Notice that eviction is active just trying to resolve problems but it didn't result.

The flow of a typical problem is next:

1.- A new Hibernate session is opened

2.- I check just before of the query if this session is opened and connected

3.- After see on the logs that the session opened is valid, the exception is produced

**--ADDED**

The complete stack trace of one of the errors is this:

```
29 03 2013 10:00:00 INFO EasyApScheduler_Worker-8 com.psa.accounting.eureca.logic.EurecaNLAccountingLogic - -- Process EURECA_NL starts
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 INFO EasyApScheduler_Worker-2 com.psa.accounting.eureca.logic.EurecaSCAccountingLogic - -- Process EURECA_SC starts
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 DEBUG EasyApScheduler_Worker-2 com.xeridia.persistence.ServiceLocator - Session opened: net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@22880d66. Opened: true, Connected: true
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 DEBUG EasyApScheduler_Worker-2 com.xeridia.persistence.ServiceLocator - [getConnection]|16|Thread[EasyApScheduler_Worker-2,4,main]|
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 DEBUG EasyApScheduler_Worker-2 com.xeridia.persistence.ServiceLocator - [getConnection]|16|Thread[EasyApScheduler_Worker-2,4,main]|com.easyap.invoice.persistence.InvoiceDAOHibernate.<init>(InvoiceDAOHibernate.java:364)
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 ERROR EasyApScheduler_Worker-8 net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@1b0ca3f7 is closed.
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 DEBUG EasyApScheduler_Worker-2 com.xeridia.persistence.ServiceLocator - [getConnection]|16|Thread[EasyApScheduler_Worker-2,4,main]|com.psa.invoice.persistence.PSAInvoiceDAOHibernate.<init>(PSAInvoiceDAOHibernate.java:52)
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 ERROR EasyApScheduler_Worker-8 net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@1b0ca3f7 is closed.
    29 03 2013 10:00:00 ERROR EasyApScheduler_Worker-8 net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Could not execute query
    java.sql.SQLException: Connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@1b0ca3f7 is closed.
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.checkOpen(DelegatingConnection.java:398)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:279)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.getPreparedStatement(BatcherImpl.java:257)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.getPreparedStatement(BatcherImpl.java:232)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.prepareQueryStatement(BatcherImpl.java:65)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:779)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:265)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:133)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1033)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1024)
        at net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.list(QueryTranslator.java:854)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:1544)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:39)
        at com.xeridia.persistence.BaseDAOHibernate.findByQuery(BaseDAOHibernate.java:312)
        at com.xeridia.persistence.BaseDAOHibernate.findByQuery(BaseDAOHibernate.java:291)
        at com.psa.invoice.persistence.PSAInvoiceDAOHibernate.getAccountingInvoicesWithNoProblem(PSAInvoiceDAOHibernate.java:215)
        at com.psa.accounting.eureca.logic.EurecaNLAccountingLogic.getAccountingDataFromDB(EurecaNLAccountingLogic.java:469)
        at com.psa.accounting.eureca.logic.EurecaNLAccountingLogic.process(EurecaNLAccountingLogic.java:207)
        at com.psa.accounting.eureca.scheduler.CronEurecaNLAccounting.execute(CronEurecaNLAccounting.java:91)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

The class which manages all the Hibernate sessions is a class called ServiceLocator. The method getConnection() of this class returns a new connection and its code is next:

```
synchronized (session) {
                s = (Session) session.get();
                if ((s == null)||(!s.isOpen())) {
                    s = null;
                    s = getSessionFactory().openSession();
                    if (s != null) {
                        log.debug("Session opened: " + s + ". Opened: " + s.isOpen() +
                                ", Connected: " + s.isConnected());
                        printThreadDataForClosedConnections("[getConnection]");
                    }
                    session.set(s);
                }
                if (!s.isConnected()) {
                    s.reconnect();
                    log.debug("Session reconnected: " + s + ". Opened: " + s.isOpen() +
                            ", Connected: " + s.isConnected());
                    printThreadDataForClosedConnections("[getConnection]");
                }
            }
```

The object 'session' is declared as:

```
public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();
```

to obtain different sessions for different threads, so there shouldn't exist a problem closing sessions between threads.

What you can see in the stack trace above is that EasyApScheduler_Worker-2 obtains a new connection because of `if ((s == null)||(!s.isOpen())) {` but EasyApScheduler_Worker-8 does not, which means its 'session' objects exists and is open or fails to obtain the connection and that corresponds to the first trace of the error `29 03 2013 10:00:00 ERROR EasyApScheduler_Worker-8 net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@1b0ca3f7 is closed.`

I don't know if the problem comes from Hibernate, Postgres or Tomcat. I haven't found almost nothing about this error on Google so I hope you can give me a hand.

Please ask whatever extra information or settings you need in order to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a multithreading problem - your first log comes from a `Thread` called " EasyApAdminScheduler_Worker-2" and your exception comes from a `Thread` called "EasyApScheduler_Worker-8". Are you sharing your `Session` between `Thread`s? This isn't really advisable. In any case, presumably there is a race hazard between the first `Thread` closing the `Session` and the second thread using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Look at my original post, I added some extra information. The log trace I had wrote was wrong, it was from other thread. You are right that there are 2 Quartz processes running at the same time, but I have many other situations where there is only one Quartz process. I have no problem copying the stack trace from other different and simpler error if you want.

Comment: I still think this is a race hazard. Migration/updating often brings these to the surface. Debugging race hazards is rather difficult but you can start by attaching a debugger and putting break points in critical sections. Writing an integration test for your `ServiceLocator` that fires lots of `Thread`s at it may also help get to the bottom of it.

Comment: You may want to give up on reinventing the wheel altogether and use one of the (tested) `CurrentSessionContext` implementations bundled with hibernate. [`ManagedSessionContext`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/ManagedSessionContext.html) would seem a good fit.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll give a try to the options suggested. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed this.

It was a problem with Quartz threads. By default, Quartz manages a pool of threads which are re-used between executions of different jobs. My class ServiceLocator, which is responsible for open and close connections, is based on ThreadLocal objects. It seems that one of my schedule jobs didn't close its connection properly, and after that, all the jobs executed on the same thread as this one caused an error.

I couldn't figure out what was the problematic job, and what I finally did was change the default connection pool of Quartz for a custom one, in such a way that I make a new thread for each job execution, instead of sharing a certain amount of threads for all jobs.

Here is the Quartz custom thread pooling that I have wrote in case it could be useful for someone:

```
public class SimpleNoThreadPooling implements ThreadPool {

    public int getPoolSize() {
        return 0;
    }


    public Log getLog() {
        return LogFactory.getLog(SimpleNoThreadPooling.class);
    }

    public void initialize() throws SchedulerConfigException { }

    class WorkerThread extends Thread {

        private Runnable runnable = null;

        /**
         * <p>
         * Create a worker thread, start it, execute the runnable and terminate
         * the thread (one time execution).
         * </p>
         */
        WorkerThread(Runnable runnable) {
            this.runnable = runnable;
            start();
        }

        public void run() {
            if (runnable != null) {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } catch (Exception exceptionInRunnable) {
                    try {
                        getLog().error("Error while executing the Runnable: ",
                            exceptionInRunnable);
                    } catch(Exception e) {  
                        // ignore to help with a tomcat glitch
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean runInThread(Runnable runnable) {
        new WorkerThread(runnable);
        return true;
    }

    public void shutdown(boolean waitForJobsToComplete) { }

}
```